# Tumblr items published from queue do not show in Facebook timeline - only those items published directly

Tags: facebook, tumblr, facebook-timeline, facebook-apps

I reported the following issue to Tumblr:

> I have setup Tumblr to post to Facebook as well. However, I have
>   noticed that posts published from the queue do not appear in my
>   Facebook timeline - only posts I publish directly. can this please be
>   fixed?

And this is the reply I received:

> Facebook has altered the way it displays information from Tumblr and
>   other applications. While you should see some of your posts appearing
>   in your newsfeed, not all posts will appear there. This is to keep
>   applications from cluttering your Facebook newsfeed.
>
> Unfortunately, we can't control how Facebook displays content from
>   Tumblr.

This does not sound right to me: Tumblr would surely have been the author of a plugin - and failing to post to Facebook items that came from the queue does not sound like something on the Facebook side, but in the plugin. Is it possible that I am doing something wrong here?

-edit-
Why would Facebook discriminate between posts published from a queue and posts published directly? More importantly, HOW could they discriminate? Is this data provided by Tumblr to Facebook? Either way, this looks like a bug to me, and I believe it more likely that it's a bug on the Tumblr side and I am disappointed that Tumblr apparently will not even investigate.

Comment: You could try using a third-party service like [http://ifttt.com/](http://ifttt.com)  and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion @FelixBonkoski - I will give this a try for some other channels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though @FelixBonkoski's ifttt seems good, I found my solution a different way: I had already set up Tumblr to publish automatically to Twitter.. And thankfully Twitter can publish to Facebook, and this seems to work well for me - for items published from the queue or directly.

Comment: Good to know.  It's still strange, however that the queued Tumblr posts are being treated differently by Facebook.  I'm still suspecting it's a Tumblr problem. And their cryptic email reply does nothing to clarify the issue.  I would send a follow up email to support, explaining to them that now, pushing your posts from Tumblr -> Twitter -> Facebook, there are *no issues*, as there are with Tumblr -> Facebook.  I'd like to see what support has to say about that.